# Nesting WHENs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I want to do a SELECT along the lines of

```
CASE
    WHEN Status = 'Live'
        THEN
            WHEN BookingDate = LastModifiedDateTime
                THEN
                    'New'
                ELSE
                    'Modified'
        ELSE
            Status
    END AS s
```

I run into an issue with the second `WHEN`

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'.

I'm unsure how I may fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't nest `WHEN`, you can nest `CASE`:

```
CASE
    WHEN Status = 'Live'
        THEN
            CASE WHEN BookingDate = LastModifiedDateTime
                THEN
                    'New'
                ELSE
                    'Modified'
            END
        ELSE
            Status
END AS s
```

Personally, I would write it like:

```
CASE
    WHEN Status = 'Live' AND BookingDate = LastModifiedDateTime
         THEN 'New'
    WHEN Status = 'Live'
         THEN 'Modified'
    ELSE Status
END AS s
```